# ターミナルでのanacondaのインストールについて

Tags: python, anaconda

最近オライリーの入門python3を見ながら勉強し始めましたプログラミング初心者です。
anaconda3-4.0.0をpyenvでダウンロードしようとすると、止まったまま動きません。長い時間の後一度進んだのですが、エラーも出ます。(エラー内容を覚えていません、、、)
アナコンダ自体は、ホームページからダウンロードして、同じバージョンが/Users/私の名前/anaconda/bin/anacondaに入っています。しかし、globalではインストールされていないと出て、sublime text3では、sublimeREPLのpython（なぜかpython3とは表示されない）を押すと3.5.1がでてきます。(python --versionではpythonもanacondaも最新の状態で記録されています。)

質問が３つあるのですが
1:ホームページとターミナルの両方からインストールする必要が前提的にないのか。
2:インストールしたアナコンダの保存する場所は今の状態で大丈夫か。
3:他にインストールしたほうがいいもの、勉強方法など。

を教えていただけると助かります。また、確認したいことなどあれば是非ご連絡ください。

よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

anaconda でインストールしたもろもろのプログラム群は、質問文で記述されているように、 `~/anaconda3` にインストールされます。これは、正常な挙動です。普段使っている python を anaconda のものにしたい場合には、 .bashrc などで PATH の頭に追記してやると、多分できるはずです。 (anaconda インストール時のオプションとして、これを行うこともできる、ただデフォルトは No でそうはならない)

質問者様がやりたいことは、 sublime text で利用される python を、 anaconda のものにしたい、なのではないかと思っています。その場合、どうやって設定を行ったらよいかは、今話されている sublime text のプラグインの実装(が定める設定の行い方) と、それを実行している OS に依存すると思っています。これがやりたいことである場合、その方法についての行う質問を、別途作成いただけますでしょうか? というのも、その場合の質問はおそらく、「sublimeREPL で利用する python を anaconda のものにしたい」になると思っていて、質問を見にくる人の層が変わり、質問者様が欲しいと思っている回答が得やすくなるのでは、と思っているからです。

Answer (score 0):

1  両方からインストールする必要はありません。
２　大丈夫だと思います。
３　pipコマンドを使い、anacondaなどのツール等を入れる方がいいです。